# One foreign key for two columns

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have two tables, `Results` and `Teams`

`Teams` has the following columns:

```
team_id
team_name
```

`Results` has the following columns:

```
match_id
home_team (foreign key references teams [team_id])
away_team (foreign key references teams [team_id])
score
yellow_cards
red_cards
```

When I write query:

```
select team_name, score 
FROM teams, results 
WHERE results.home_team = teams.team_id
  AND results.away_team = teams.team_id
```

it would give me empty set.

Is it issue with the fact that I use same foreign key for two different columns in the same table?

Answer (score 10):

The query results are correct, as your query finds all teams and results where a team played against itself (`home_team = away_team`).

You probably want to use 2 joins to `teams` in you query:

```
SELECT 
    home.team_name AS home_team_name, 
    away.team_name AS away_team_name, 
    r.score 
FROM 
    results AS r
  JOIN teams AS home 
    ON r.home_team = home.team_id
  JOIN teams AS away 
    ON r.away_team = away.team_id ;
```

Comment: The above revised query is correct. The issue was that whilst the schema is okay, the original query was selecting where the home and away teams are the same (which does not make sense - different teams play each other).